# Java Better way to create memory efficient static methods

Tags: java, class, static

I have a class `Repo` with following definition:

```
class Repo
{
    private final record Table(String name,List<String[]> columns){}
    private static final Map<Integer,Table> TABLES = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(0, new Table("item 1", List.of(
                                                 new String[]{"A","B","C"},
                                                 new String[]{"AA","BB","CC"},
                                                 //... Long list of String[]
                                                 ))),
        Map.entry(1, new Table("item 2", List.of(
                                                 new String[]{"D","E","F"},
                                                 new String[]{"DD","EE","FF"},
                                                 //... Long list of String[]
                                                 ))),
        //... More entries
    );

    protected static String getTableName(int index)
    {
        return TABLES.get(index).name();
    }
    
    private static List<String[]> getColumns(int index)
    {
        return TABLES.get(index).columns();
    }
    protected static String initTables(int index)
    {
        var table = getTableName(index);
        var columns = getColumns(index).append(",");
        var builder = new StringBuilder(table).append(",")
        for(var col: columns)
        {
            builder.append(col[0]).append(",").append(col[1]).append(",").append(col[2]);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

My question is, The `initTables` function is called only once by another method `connect()` which itself resides in a class `Model` whose scope is throughout the program life, whereas `getTableName` will be called numerous times by various methods. Since the `TABLES` and `initTables` are static, they'll remain in the memory throughout the program. is there any way to remove them from space once they are done?

I thought of creating a separate class for `TABLES` called `TableColumns` having only columns and create its instance in the `initTables`:

```
class Repo
{
private static final Map<Integer,String> TableNames = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry(0, "item 1"),
    Map.entry(1, "item 2"),
    //... more entries
);

protected String getTableName(int index)
{
    return TABLES.get(index);
}

protected String initTables(int index)
{
    var table = getTableName(index);
    var builder = new StringBuilder(index).append(",");
    var tablecolumns = new TableColumns().getColumns(index);
    for(var col:tablecolumns)
    {
        ...
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

**TableColumns class**

```
public TableColumns
{
    private static final Map<Integer,List<String[]>> TABLES = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(0, List.of(
                             new string[]{...},
                             //... more String[]
        )),
        //... more entries
    );
    
    public TableColumns(){}
    protected List<String[]> getColumns(int index)
    {
        return TABLES.get(index);
    }
}
```

Will this optimize memory usage or is there any better way of achieving this?

Comment: are you worried that bytecode for `initTables` function is stored in memory? or you think that local variables will be stored permanently?

Comment: Yes I'm thinking of removing `initTables` from memory after its done, and correct me if I'm wrong, but it'll stay in memory because `Repo` is a nested static class and each time `getTableName` is called, whole of the class will be instantiated, `TABLES` and `initTables` included?

Comment: class will be instantiated only one time during first call, method's code takes minimal amount of space, so the only real memory consumer is TABLES variable, which is also will be instantiated only one time, the same for TableColumns class - it will be instantiated one time with its static variable as well, so it will not decrease memory consumption

Comment: if you really need to save memory (which I really doubt), then you can put table names in one static array (not map, just string[]) so it will be preserved between calls in memory, and columns store in another array (String[][]) as local variable in getColumns method, so it can be deallocated by GC

Comment: IMHO this is premature optimization. The code of the methods is maybe a few 100 bytes and the data itself maybe up to 20'000 bytes. How much memory does your application use? 500MB? Then this init data takes up about 0.04% of the total space.

Comment: It might make more sense to think about putting this data into a configuration file that is read during startup (and the memory for this initialization task can be reclaimed without problems)

Comment: So should I just let `Repo` be what it initially was?
@ThomasKläger that sounds like a very good idea. I can make separate external files for the `List<String[]>` for each tablenames, and load them as they are called. It'll increase IO momentarily but that's better, and I need only edit those files to change the columns in the future without having to edit the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Thomas Klager, I turned the `item1`, `item2` etc. entries into external text files, and modified `initTables` as such:

```
protected String initTables(int index)
{
    var tableName=getTableName(index);
    try(var scanner=new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(tableName))
    {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```